# ios swift tableview not showing custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, tableview

I am trying to create a table view with custom cells from Storyboard layout in an iOS app.

But for some reason the table cells are not being shown. When I tried to set debug breakpoints I found that the debugger is reaching this function

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

but it never reaches this function -

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Here is my viewcontroller code -

```
extension NavigationViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SideMenuControllerDelegate {

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SideMenuTableItem
        cell.setItemData(items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func setupTableViews() {
        menuTable.register(SideMenuTableItem.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem")

    }
}

class SideMenuTableItem: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuLabel: UILabel!

    var data: MenuItem?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func setItemData(_ item: MenuItem) {
        data = item
        menuLabel.text = data?.title
        if data?.icon_res != nil {
            menuImage.image = UIImage(named: (data?.icon_res)!)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I have checked in the storyboard that I have set the reusable identifier to the table prototype cell and also connected the datasource and the delegate properties to the tableview

[image: cellidentifier]
[image: datasource,delegate references]
[image: other tableview properties]
[image: debugging results]

and I am calling the setupTableViews() method inside my viewDidLoad() function after creating the items array 
But still I am not able to get the cells to appear in my view at all. 
Can anyone suggest what am I missing here or what's wrong with my code, or how can I further debug this issue

```
import UIKit
import SideMenuSwift

class NavigationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var userAvatar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userProfile: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuTable: UITableView!

    var service: AuthenticationService!
    var cdc: CoreDataController!
    var items: [MenuItem] = []
    var currentUser: User?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSidebar()
        initSidebarData()
        setupUserHeader()
        setupTableViews()
    }

    func setupUserHeader() {
        if currentUser != nil {
            if currentUser?.name != nil {
                userName.text = currentUser?.name
            } else if currentUser?.role != nil {
                userName.text = "urTutors " + (currentUser?.role ?? "")
            }
            if currentUser?.avatarUrl != nil {
                userAvatar.downloaded(from: (currentUser?.avatarUrl)!)
            }
        }
    }

    func initSidebarData() {
        service = AuthenticationServiceProvider()
        cdc = CoreDataController()
        items = cdc.getNavigationData()
        currentUser = cdc.getUserData()
    }

    func setupSidebar() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexColor("#fff")
        navigationContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexColor("#2a2a2a")
        SideMenuController.preferences.basic.statusBarBehavior = .hideOnMenu
        SideMenuController.preferences.basic.position = .above
        SideMenuController.preferences.basic.direction = .left
        SideMenuController.preferences.basic.enablePanGesture = true
        SideMenuController.preferences.basic.menuWidth = 275
        sideMenuController?.delegate = self
    }

    static func createViewController() -> NavigationViewController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "StudentHomeModuleStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationViewController")
        return vc as! NavigationViewController
    }
}
```

--UPDATE--

updated setupTableLayout function -

```
func setupTableViews() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "SideMenuTableItem", bundle: bundle)
        menuTable.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem")
        menuTable.register(SideMenuTableItem.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem")
        menuTable.reloadData()
    }
```

[image: outlets]

Comment: Yes, I tried to search for and follow along many available guides but I am still not able to get it working and hence the post here

Comment: What does `items.count` return? If it is zero, `cellForRow` will not be called.

Comment: It returns 8, yes non-zero value

Comment: Does you tableview actually visible; constraint problems can cause no cells to be displayed. Set your tables background colour to something distinctive and make sure it is a actually visible

Comment: and you know cellForRow isn't being called because you put a breakpoint in it?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try `override func` instead of `public func`.

Comment: Override is only needed if you are subclassing a tableviewcontroller

Comment: yeah it wouldn't even compile if the function signature were wrong. cellForRow, as you have it, is required by the UITableViewDataSource protocol. Mess it up and Xcode would tell you.

Comment: I'm not clear what debugging you've already done. If you add a breakpoint to `cellForRow`, it never gets hit? And if you add a breakpoint to `numberOfRowsInSection`, and `po items`, you see an array of 8 items? If so, what do you see if you `po tableView`?

Comment: @Koen yes override doesn't help and clarus - I tried removing the breakpoint but still it did not work, also yes you are correct regarding the debugging. Updated the post with debugging result screenshot of po tableView

Comment: Where do you call reloadData? after your call to `setupTableViews`?

Comment: It wasn't working with any thing that I tried so I was attempting and hoping that this reloadData will make it work

Comment: I'm still not seeing where you're calling reloadData. Does the breakpoint still not get hit if you add `menuTable.reloadData` at the end of `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Why do you need setupTableViews()?  Are you using a xib file to create a `tableViewCell`?  It doesn't look like you have a xib file.

Comment: @clarus I thought I added reloadData earlier but dropped it when it didn't work once. But now it seems to be working with the reloadData addition

Comment: Do you have a custom cell class xib to go along with the custom class, as El Tomato  mentioned? if not, your cell class outlets are nil and you will crash when you try to set text in the labels. I don't see one in your project.

Comment: Wait a second. Your custom class is using outlets, but you're using the register call in setupTableViews that takes a class, not a nib name. You can't use outlets without a nib or storyboard. That's why your outlets are nil and you're crashing. either use a xib or create the labels programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

After breaking into chat on this, we found that there were two issues.

The first issue was the missing `reloadData` call mentioned above. That was causing `cellForRow` to not be called. Adding `reloadData` corrected that issue, but then the custom cell class's outlets were nil, causing a crash in `setItemData`.

The second issue was that `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` was being called in code, but the custom cell was already setup as part of the Interface Builder `UITableView` declaration. Calling `register` again on the custom class re-registered the `reuseIdentifier`, disconnecting the outlets set up in the storyboard.

Removing the `register` call and adding `reloadData` solved all issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling `setupTableViews()`. You'r code should look like this:

```
class NavigationViewController: UIViewController, SideMenuControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableViews()
    }

func setupTableViews() {
menuTable.reloadData()
    }
}

extension NavigationViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SideMenuTableItem
        cell.setItemData(items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

You are never calling the function, nor calling viewDidLoad. This should help. Also, where is the rest of your view controller code (is this all of it? It should not be!).

You don't need to register your cell because you requested it and make sure you reloadData().

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, I am calling this setupTableViews method inside videDidLoad. Updated the post with the rest of the controller code

Comment: Please try call `menuTable.reloadData()` after you register you'r cell in the `setupTableViews()` function. Like in my answer.

Comment: Yes, reloadData seems to help. but now I am getting "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in this line of the table cell class - menuLabel.text = data?.title

Comment: Ok so now the problem is that `data?.title` doesn't exist. You need to make sure it exists otherwise just return an empty string. It looks like some of the data from `cdc.getNavigationData()` isn't being returned to the array properly.

Comment: it exists, I have checked and so does the menuTable. I even tried with if data?.title != nil { menuLabel.text = data?.title } but getting the same error again

Comment: Try this: `menuLabel.text = data?.title ?? ""`, this will return an empty string if the one dosen't exist.

Comment: i think your outlets are nil. do you have a xib corresponding to that class with those outlets hooked up? I don't see it in your project tree.

Comment: Yes, I did check my outlets they are added correctly. Attached a screenshot of the same in the updated post. Also tried setting the default value to data?.title ?? "". 
Tried using the nibs as suggested and updated the post with the updated setupTableLayout function. But still getting the same error. But, maybe I am loading the nibs incorrectly @clarus can you look at the updated setupTableViews function to see if I am registering the nibs correctly now

Comment: I'm talking about the outlets in your custom cell class.

Comment: so, no, that's not quite right. remove the first register, and in the xib for the second, set the cell class to your custom cell class. that's all you need.

Comment: ah, yeah that looks right. sorry, the images are a bit hard to read. So, yeah, just remove the first register in that setupTableViews method. Your custom cell class will be used because it's used in the xib that the other register call references.

Comment: so if I remove the first register method the function now looks like - func setupTableViews() {
        menuTable.register(SideMenuTableItem.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem")
        menuTable.reloadData()
    } 
but still I am getting the same error on the outlets "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in this line - 
menuLabel.text = data?.title ?? ""

Comment: This is what you want: `menuTable.register(UINib(nibName: "SideMenuTableItem", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTableItem")` you can break that into lines if you want, but just use nil for the bundle.

Comment: This register method throws this exception - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/harshitladdha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6E686690-AB7E-41E9-9F5D-2FDB61F6CAE9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/54F01CFF-C920-4C9E-B355-564F0A3F554A/Photostream.app> (loaded)' with name 'SideMenuTableItem''

Comment: sorry, I'm still having trouble reading those images. Do you have a separate xib for your custom class, or do you just reference it in the storyboard?

Comment: ah exactly. ok, you don't have a separate xib.

Comment: ok, you don't even need to register that cell type. it's referenced in your storyboard. just make sure you have the cell identifier set correctly there. So, you don't even need to call `register`.

Comment: when you right-click on the SideMenuTableItem protoype cell on the left side object nav in your storyboard, do you see any yellow triangles, or are the outlets showing as connected correctly? and again, make sure to set up your reuse identifier in the inspector there.

Comment: No warning signs in the prototype cell, and the outlets are showing correctly. Image uploaded here - https://imgur.com/a/qomnxWr

Comment: ok, and the reuseIdentifier is set in the ib inspector and you've removed the register code? I think that should do it... :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190973/discussion-between-deadman-and-clarus).